# How should I plot a tight-binding dispersion when I use multiple gridpoints in real space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dispersion, tight-binding

Consider a simple tightbinding calculation with spacing $a$. I can write down a dispersion relation $$E(k) = 2t - te^{ika} - te^{-ika}$$

Say I am solving a simple tightbinding problem numerically, on a grid with three points. This can be solved by getting the eigenvalues of the matrix $$\mathbf M(k) = \begin{bmatrix}2t&-t&-te^{ika}\\-t&2t&-t\\-te^{-ika}&-t&2t\end{bmatrix}$$You can see however that for each $k$, I get three eigenvalues. If I wanted to plot these eigenvalues and $k$-points in the style of the dispersion above, how would I do so? I.e. When I use the first expression, then for each $k$, I get one $E$, and so I can plot $E(k)$ vs $k$. When I use the second expression, then for each $k$ I get three $E$ and I don't know how to plot $E(k)$ vs $k$ when, for each $k$, I have three $E$ instead of one.

Comment: This question is not complete, or rather what you are asking for is ambiguous.  Are you asking for analytic expressions for the eigenvalues that you can then plot? Are you asking how to plot it in particular computing software?  I mean, you get three functions of k, which you can plot, so what are you really asking for here?

Comment: When I use the first expression, then for each k, I get one E, and so I can plot E(k) vs k. When I use the second expression, then for each k I get three E and I don't know how to plot E(k) vs k when, for each k, I have three E instead of one.